# What does "type var[]" mean?

Tags: arrays, syntax, vala

I accidently wrote this code:

```
int main(string args[]) {
  stderr.printf ("Usage: %s", args[0]);
  return 1;
}
```

What I meant was:

```
int main(string[] args) {
  stderr.printf ("Usage: %s", args[0]);
  return 1;
}
```

The difference is the definition of the parameter. The curious thing is that `valac` does not complain about the first version.

So what does it even mean to the compiler if I say `type var[]` instead of `type[] var`?

From the generated C code it seems like the brackets are completely ignored.

Also when compiled and run this code segfaults.

PS: My Vala version is 0.32.1 (and 0.34.8 shows the same behavior).

Comment: Don't know Vala, but there are other languages that allow both forms, and they're equivalent there afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing the brackets after the var name will create a fixed-size array. If you do `string args[1]` for example, you'll get an array of size 1.

It's briefly discussed at the bottom of this tutorial:
https://chebizarro.gitbooks.io/the-vala-tutorial/content/arrays.html

Comment: That would not make any sense with no arguments inside the brackets though.

Comment: Because Vala does not perform bounds checking at runtime, you may be able to access array elements that are out of range. By not stating the size of the array, you're creating an array of size 0. You could then access args[1] potentially without throwing an error, but this is very unsafe because something else could be using that memory.